# how to convert html page to pdf with css using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, itext

This is my code :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);

HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

pdfDoc.Open();

**htmlparser.Parse(sr);** //the exception here

pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

the error is :

> Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type
>   'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'.

What is this exception ?

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: visit this link and try with the version of itextsharp...it may resolve your error.

Comment: http://r4r.co.in/c1/01/tutorial/csharp/Export%20gridview%20to%20pdf%20in%20asp.net%20using%20c-Sharp.shrtml.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer, but I found that iTextSharp is picky about having valid html. My tests had a table that was opened twice and never closed and that took about an hour for me to notice. The exception was very similar to the one you have there.

Answer (score 0):

use can you A4 size width & height for html deigning .

Comment: i don't think so that  i have changed width & height but the same error

Answer (score -1):

use this set od code to create pdf from html.

```
String htmlText = "<div>Your HTML text here</div>";

Document document = new Document();

PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\outfile.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet styles = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
document.Close();

Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=outfile.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\outfile.pdf");
Response.Flush();
Response.Clear();
```