# HTML isn't rendered as PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I'm working on an internal system for our transport department for which I'm using the iTextSharp library.

Everything is done so far but the PDF generation isn't working as expected. When a user presses the "Submit" button the system generates a PDF file.

I have used this example for inspiraction:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

The generation of a PDF file succeeds: IE asks me to open or download the file, but when I press open, I don't get what I expect...

I have a snippet of the form is passed to the above code:

```
//var theForm = document.forms['frm_transport']; if (!theForm) { theForm = document.frm_transport; }
Laden/Lossen: tot uur.
Bezorgen op:
Staat klaar:
Transportnummer
Afleveradres
Bedrijf:
T.a.v.
Adres:
Postcode:
Plaats
Provincie:
Land:
Telefoon:
Transport kosten
Prioriteit: NormaalSpoed
Kosten: Selecteer...Ontvangervoor Organistatie
SPOED: Wanneer moet deze aangeleverd worden?
Datum:
Tijd:
Indien transportkosten voor organistatie kosten afboeken op:
Kostenplaats:

> Projectcode:
Indien voor rekening ontvanger:
Klantnummer
Opmerkingen
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) { if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() !=
false)) { theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget; theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value =
eventArgument; theForm.submit(); } } //
```

I see that the system is not filling the CSS and the filled forms. It's only "copying" the RAW html data.

And it's including RAW Javascript code for an unknown reason.

**What did I try**

I see that an other user [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486093/how-to-convert-html-page-to-pdf-with-css-using-itextsharp) asked the same, but then I must re-write my HTML code again.

What am I missing here? I'm a beginner regarding C#.net and iTextSharp.

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is deprecated in favor of XML Worker. See http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker for XML Worker examples. (By the way: I'm the author of iText and I understand Dutch.)

Comment: I've edited your question and noticed several things that are wrong: (1) I don't see any HTML in your snippet, (2) you expect the HTML parser to interpret JavaScript (it doesn't), (3) you mention CSS, but I don't see any (and parsing CSS is only supported in XML Worker), (4) You mention (HTML?) Forms, but HTML Forms can't be converted to PDF (forms in PDF are inherently different than forms in HTML). You'll have to go back to the drawing board and design the PDF part of your application.

Comment: My idea was that: When I or a user is pressing the submit button the form between <asp:form runat="server"> HTML FORM </form> must be "printed" into a pdf file.

Comment: If you really need the HTML inside the form tags, you could parse the HTML in between the <asp:form> tags yourself using XmlWorker and create the form fields (instead of letting iText/XmlWorker do it). But an easier and more straightforward way would be to just send the form data to the server and process it/turn it into a PDF there. If you're still keen on using HTML to make a PDF, insert the data into an HTML that you made to resemble the form and parse it with XmlWorker (YMMV).